# Postgresql Syntax for a Self Join, appropriately naming left and right sides of same table, using Ruby on Rails:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, self-join

I have a table "QualifyingEvents" with columns for class_date, course_id, sponsor_name, and confirmed.  I am trying to extract partially matching records, some with incomplete data, following the self join example in the Postgresql 9.3.5 documentation (2.6. Joins Between Tables):

```
  SELECT W1.city, W1.temp_lo AS low, W1.temp_hi AS high,
      W2.city, W2.temp_lo AS low, W2.temp_hi AS high
      FROM weather W1, weather W2
      WHERE W1.temp_lo < W2.temp_lo
      AND W1.temp_hi > W2.temp_hi;

       city      | low | high |     city      | low | high
  ---------------+-----+------+---------------+-----+------
   San Francisco |  43 |   57 | San Francisco |  46 |   50
   Hayward       |  37 |   54 | San Francisco |  46 |   50
  (2 rows)
```

They note that "we have relabeled the weather table as W1 and W2 to be able to distinguish the left and right side of the join."  So, here's my attempt:

```
  QualifyingEvent.select("w1.class_date", "w1.course_id", "w1.sponsor_name", "w2.class_date", "w2.course_id", "w2.sponsor_name").from("qualifying_events w1", "qualifying_events w2").where("confirmed IS NULL")
```

I'm getting this error:

```
  PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "w2"
```

Removing the quotes from "qualifying_events w1" and "qualifying_events w2" triggers this error:

```
  syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
```

So, I tried relabeling the table as "qualifying_events_w1" and "qualifying_events_w2" and I get this error:

```
  PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "qualifying_events_w1" does not exist
```

Here's my schema:

```
  a_test_development=# \dt
                    List of relations
   Schema |         Name          | Type  |   Owner    
  --------+-----------------------+-------+------------
   public | admins                | table | anon
   public | qualifying_events     | table | anon
   public | schema_migrations     | table | anon
   public | users                 | table | anon
```

Incidentally, I know matching records exist because I manually created them.

I think the problem is how one defines the left and right sides of a table using ruby on rails with postgresql.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
your_table = \
  QualifyingEvent.joins("
    INNER JOIN qualifying_events AS t2 ON (
      (qualifying_events.temp_lo < t2.temp_lo)
      AND
      (qualifying_events.temp_hi < t2.temp_hi)
      AND
      (qualifying_events.confirmed IS NULL)
    )
  ").select("
    qualifying_events.temp_lo AS w1_temp_lo,
    qualifying_events.temp_hi AS w1_temp_hi,
    t2.temp_lo AS w2_temp_lo,
    t2.temp_lo AS w2_temp_hi,
  ") # add more columns to 'select' in a similar way
```

Add the `t2.confirmed IS NULL` condition in the `joins` conditions if it's a requirement.

You can access the columns like so:

```
row = your_table.first
row.w1_temp_lo
row.w2_temp_hi # etc.
```

Comment: Humza - Thank you for answering.  I've not quite sure what's being returned.  I assumed that I'd find duplicate records, i.e., complete and incomplete ones that matched on two fields.  The response - empty arrays - follows.  (In the next comment; I'm short on space.) Incidentally, I removed the confirmed is null condition.  There are several records that match on these fields, some complete and some incomplete that I manually created.

Comment: QualifyingEvent Load (17.1ms)  SELECT qualifying_events.class_date AS w1_class_date, qualifying_events.sponsor_name AS w1_sponsor_name, t2.class_date AS w2_class_date, t2.sponsor_name AS w2_sponsor_name FROM "qualifying_events" INNER JOIN qualifying_events AS t2 ON ((qualifying_events.class_date < t2.class_date) AND (qualifying_events.sponsor_name < t2.sponsor_name))

=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<QualifyingEvent id: nil>, #<QualifyingEvent id: nil>, #<QualifyingEvent id: nil>, #<QualifyingEvent id: nil>, ...]>

Comment: ID is nil because you aren't adding in your selected columns. Even if it is nil though, you can still access the other attributes. Like `results.first.w1_class_date`

Comment: Humza - Thank you again.  Code works.  Have a great New Year's!